# Jenkins testlink plugin how to fetch remote JUnit report

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins setup in machine A and Testlink in machine B. Jenkins is connected to Testlink via Testlink Plugin. I scheduled a job via Jenkins that runs a python script via on machine B (via SSH) and the script generates JUnit report XML file. Now I'm am clueless about how  I can get Jenkins-Testlink plugin to fetch the JUnit report from machine A?

I need to do this because the result seeking strategy is a certain Class name in the JUnit XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plug-ins is supposed to try to serialize your results from your slave to the master. It uses the Jenkins plug-in API and FilePath, FWIW.

Try adding a JUnit result seeking strategy (test case name, test suite, etc), and add the right pattern to match the file results in your slave (machine B?). You can use ant patterns, like **/*.xml, that means recursively look inside each directory for *.xml files.

Feel free to open an issue in http://issues.jenkins-ci.org, using component testlink in case it doesn't work. It will get automatically assigned to me.

Thanks!
Bruno